# background worker in asp.net

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I migrate my winforms crawler app to a asp.net web app and would like to know how to implement the background worker thread that I use for very long searches?

Another posting mentioned asynchronous pages but I am not sure if this would work or how to apply it. The search function that would run can sometimes run for a few days and I would like the user to have the option to perform other functions still.

Can this happen?

Answer (score 3):

Several days??? Please don't put something like this in an ASP.NET application. Use a Windows NT service, a console application whatever but if you monopolize threads in an ASP.NET application for several days this application won't likely handle many users.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess as a newbie it  was a stupid question. I have a forms application that runs well but just thought of creating a web interface for it and have the application still run as a standalone thing. Thanks, I will look into your suggestions.

Comment: Is there any suggestions towards creating a web interface for this app that typically will only be used by me or at most 2 people.